# git filter-branch partially lost history

Tags: git, git-filter-branch, git-history

I had a repo in one folder and I splitted this into submodules a while ago.

initial: (T0)

```
-mainpackage
\-subpackage1
\-subpackage2
```

current:(T1)

```
-subpackage1
-subpackage2
-mainpackage
```

Currently I can see all git history from the beginning. now I want to move this subpackage1 into another repo.

when I perform a surgery and filter the branch with `git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter <directory of subpackage1> -- --all` I lose the history between T0 and T1 which is the most of the commits.

when I trace the history with `git log --follow --pretty=format:"%H" <filename>`, i see same file had two versions latest ones with path to the file (like 'subpackage/src/../filename') and old commits with only file name (like 'filename').

How can I recover past history for the whole submodule (best case) or specific files (worst case - I am only interested in history of 4-5 files)

Comment: Git doesn't actually have *file history*. The only history in any repository consists of the commits in the repository. The filter-branch command works by copying (some or all of) the old commits to new ones; you then stop using the old ones and start using the new and supposedly improved ones instead. If the new commits are not the history you wanted, you'll need a different set of copies. Make sure you copied all the commits you wanted to keep.

Comment: What `git log --follow <path>` does is: start at the *last* commit(s) (as specified on the command line by branch names, if you used any, or as specified by HEAD otherwise). Then, walk back through all commits, one at a time. If *this* commit, on the walk, changes the specified file, *print* it. If not, don't print it. If the way it changes the file is to *rename* the file from `dir2/newfile.ext` to `dir1/oldfile.ext`, start looking for `dir1/oldfile.ext` from the next (well, previous) commit on back towards the beginning of time.

Comment: If your filter-branch copied all commits in which `dir2/*` files exist but threw out all `dir1/*` files during the copying, and omitted commits in which there were no `dir2/*` files, well, then the new history, made by copying only `dir2/*`-commit-containing files (and even then only the `dir2/*` parts of them), won't have any `dir1/*` files. So `--follow` won't see a rename and won't switch to looking for `dir1/oldfile.ext`.

Comment: You will need to come up with a different filter—one other than `--subdirectory-filter`—so that you keep files *not* named `subpackage1/*` in those earlier commits. What name you give those files in the copies of those commits is up to you / your filters.

Comment: with follow I can see all history, so actually I have the hashes of all commits. subdirectory filter skips the commits from the old folder. I tried index filtering but this also cleared old commits

Comment: Yes, `--subdirectory-filter` means "discard the files that aren't in the subdirectory", i.e., the *new* commits (result of copying) don't touch (or even have) files outside the subdirectory. If you write your own `--index-filter`, you can choose what to keep and what to throw out, but there's no easy method.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve your problem with **[git_filter_repo](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/)** passing as parameter all paths in which the file(s) existed.

e.g.

git-filter-repo --path mainpackage/subpackage1 --path subpackage1